# Android: Could not find any matches for com.wix:detox:+ as no versions of com.wix:detox are available

Tags: android, react-native, detox

I had everything working with Detox (RN).
Then I decided to add `--production` to `npm install`, this is supposed to skip devDependencies (this is where detox dep resides).
After that, `./gradlew assembleRelease` fails with

```
> Task :app:lintVitalRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find any matches for com.wix:detox:+ as no versions of com.wix:detox are available.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/home/overtorment/.m2/repository/com/wix/detox/maven-metadata.xml
       - file:/tmp/bw_prod/node_modules/react-native/android/com/wix/detox/maven-metadata.xml
       - file:/tmp/bw_prod/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/wix/detox/maven-metadata.xml
       - file:/tmp/bw_prod/node_modules/detox/Detox-android/com/wix/detox/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/wix/detox/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/wix/detox/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://jitpack.io/com/wix/detox/maven-metadata.xml
     Required by:
         project :app
```

I assume it tries to include detox from node_modules which doesn't exist because it was not installed by npm, and that's why it fails.

What's the recommended best practice here would be?

Quick googling showed that this should be used only as last resort:

```
lintOptions { 
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
```

(build.gradle)

obviously, adding this dep via `npm i detox --save` fixes the build, but that will ship detox in a production build, no?

Comment: Indeed, Detox' `.aar` (native code) resides under node_modules - you can't run Detox without it. I suppose this means you can't use `--production` in an environment where you'd like to run your e2e tests using Detox.

Comment: @d4vidi thanks! I understand that. But somehow Detox is involved in `lintVitalRelease` during the assembly of release build where I don't need Detox. Im not too familiar with RN and how its build for production, `lintVitalRelease` came with a default RN project I believe. How to resolve the situation?

Comment: `:app:lintVitalRelease` indirectly depends on `:app:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath`, it cannot work as long as Detox is not in the path

Comment: As an advice I can offer to try to install detox globally (along with it's deps, such as `jest`), using `npm install -g`. You will have to adjust the binary paths in the `Detox` section in `package.json`, of course. In any case, I can't recommend doing that.